# Filling Missing Date Column using groupby method

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks something like:

```
+---+----+---------------+------------+------------+
|   | id |     date1     |   date2    | days_ahead |
+---+----+---------------+------------+------------+
| 0 |  1 |    2021-10-21 | 2021-10-24 | 3          |
| 1 |  1 |    2021-10-22 | NaN        | NaN        |
| 2 |  1 |    2021-11-16 | 2021-11-24 | 8          |
| 3 |  2 |    2021-10-22 | 2021-10-24 | 2          |
| 4 |  2 |    2021-10-22 | 2021-10-24 | 2          |
| 5 |  3 |    2021-10-26 | 2021-10-31 | 5          |
| 6 |  3 |    2021-10-30 | 2021-11-04 | 5          |
| 7 |  3 |    2021-11-02 | NaN        | NaN        |
| 8 |  3 |    2021-11-04 | 2021-11-04 | 0          |
| 9 |  4 |    2021-10-28 | NaN        | NaN        |
+---+----+---------------+------------+------------+
```

I am trying to fill the missing data with the days_ahead median of each id group,

**For example:**
***Median*** of **id** 1 = 5.5 which rounds to 6 
***filled value*** of **date2 at index 1** should be **2021-10-28**

Similarly, for **id** 3 Median = 5
***filled value*** of **date2 at index 7** should be **2021-11-07**

And,
for **id** 4 Median = NaN
***filled value*** of **date2 at index 9** should be **2021-10-28**

---

**I Tried**

```
df['date2'].fillna(df.groupby('id')['days_ahead'].transform('median'), inplace = True)
```

But this fills with int values.

Although, I can use lambda and apply methods to identify int and turn it to date, How do I directly use groupby and fillna together?

Comment: Did you try pd.DateOffset? Something like `df['date2'].fillna(df.date1+pd.DateOffset(df.groupby('id')['days_ahead'].transform('median'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can round values with convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), add to `date1` with `fill_value`parameter and replace missing values:

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])

td = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('id')['days_ahead'].transform('median').round(), unit='d')
df['date2'] = df['date2'].fillna(df['date1'].add(td, fill_value=pd.Timedelta(0)))

print (df)
   id      date1      date2  days_ahead
0   1 2021-10-21 2021-10-24         3.0
1   1 2021-10-22 2021-10-28         NaN
2   1 2021-11-16 2021-11-24         8.0
3   2 2021-10-22 2021-10-24         2.0
4   2 2021-10-22 2021-10-24         2.0
5   3 2021-10-26 2021-10-31         5.0
6   3 2021-10-30 2021-11-04         5.0
7   3 2021-11-02 2021-11-07         NaN
8   3 2021-11-04 2021-11-04         0.0
9   4 2021-10-28 2021-10-28         NaN
```